# Manual Transmission Driving in Reverse Clicking

Tags: transmission, reverse

Nissan Almera 1.5 N16 2006 manual transmission.

Last night whilst driving, when engaging the reverse gear, I could hear a clear clicking sound whilst moving in reverse (not stationary). Not sure whether clutch or gearbox related?

I'm sure it's not suspension components as had them replaced recently and when coming out of gear and car still rolling backwards no clicking.

On a separate but related issue a mechanic recently advised me to change the clutch fluid as when engaging reverse there is a crunch, is this clutch related I thought it would be gearbox related? The crunch has been there ever since I got the car several years back and thought it was synchro related?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule you must come to complete stop before shifting in reverse. Similarly
when downshifting into 1st from 2nd gear. If memory serves the scynchos  mesh as you shift up 1-2 2-3 3-4 4-5 and back down to 2nd but from 2-1  or R this isn't a scyncro for that. If you are going in 1st or R while you are moving you will grind the gears.

Comment: Appreciate the info. Yes well aware that one should come to a complete stop. However even then going into reverse there is a grind. Even going into gear 1 - reverse or gear 1 - 2 - reverse grinds, occasionally it doesn't. The issue I am experiencing now though is driving in reverse there is a constant clicking sound.